# Delay macro to allow events to finish

Tags: excel, vba

While attempting to access an external API function set from within a macro I found it necessary to add in a delay to allow time for the external API to process a selection.

Implementing this caused a bit of difficulty as using Application.Wait or Application.Sleep wouldn't work.

Searching online led me to try using GetTickCount or timeGetTime - both of which failed to work for me as the delay function failed to exit.

The question thus is how can I implement this?

Comment: For the purposes of a Google search this question should be titled "Excel VBA code for a delay macro to allow events to finish"

Comment: I believe we try to avoid repeating the tags in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead I implemented the delay using the functions Now and DateAdd:

```
Function Delay(Seconds As Long)
    Dim StopTime As Date: StopTime = DateAdd("s", Seconds, Now)
    Do While Now < StopTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Function
```

> **Updated below for millisecond precision**

```
Function Delay(Seconds As Double)
    Dim StopTime As Double: StopTime = Timer + Seconds
    Do While Timer < StopTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Function
```

> **For asynchronous events, the following may work but is currently untested**

```
Function DelayForAsync()
    Dim CalculationState As Long
    With Application
        CalculationState = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
        Do Until .CalculationState = xlDone
            DoEvents
        Loop
        .Calculation = CalculationState
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple Excel VBA delay function which can be written as a "one liner".

```
Sub sbD(d As Long): Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To d: DoEvents: Next i: End Sub
```

Here is a test routine to show how it would be used. The advantage of using `DoEvents` is that it is effectively non-modal and the rest of the Excel can be viewed during a delay. The routine has been tested on both Windows 11 and MacOS 14.0 Sonoma using an Office 365 subscription.

```
Option Explicit

    Sub sbD(d As Long): Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To d: DoEvents: Next i: End Sub

    Sub sbTestDelay()
    
     MsgBox "Start"
    
     ' the length of the delay will depend on how busy the computer is at the time
    
     sbD (1000000)
    
     MsgBox "End"
    
    End Sub
```