# VBA update existing PPT charts from Excel - too much memory?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, charts, powerpoint

I have searched for months to find an answer to my problem and think I'm close, but not sure how to rectify it. All my VBA knowledge comes from Google, Stack Overflow, & various forums so please excuse the state of my code.

**Overall goal:**
I have a PPT template file containing 1 template slide that has several charts full of "dummy" data, formatted exactly how I need it. I also have an Excel master file containing data on a particular sheet (also contains the VBA). I need to duplicate the template slide for `numNames` data rows, then on each slide populate the charts (and other items) with the real data contained in each row.

**The issues:**

1. Very low reliability of this code at scale. This code works well with `numNames` < ~15. If I have more rows of data/slides to populate, the code fails.
2. Sometimes graphs will "disappear" after populating with data leading to errors in later subs. This can happen to any of the circular graphs on any slide. I added `.Refresh` and `.DoEvents` to fix this, to no avail. [Missing Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meYwG.png)
3. PPT sucks up a ton of available memory if I populate the charts too quickly  which I think contributes to some of my headaches (hence the `Application.Wait`). I am using a work laptop running 64 bit Excel/PPT with approx 4GB RAM available at most times. Peak PPT memory usage ~1.3GB while inside loop. Not sure what is going on here.

I have tried `Application.ScreenUpdating = false` and it helps a bit, but the issues above still occur.

I believe all of my problems stem from how I'm populating these graphs with the real data, but so far I have not found any better solutions. I am looking for any advice on how to populate these graphs in a better/quicker way, or generally clean up this code so that it runs more smoothly. Thanks.

If you want to skip the setup portion of this sub, just ctrl+F `'$`

*some code here is not my own, not taking credit for any code I did not personally write

```
Option Explicit

'Excel
Public ProjectName As String
Public NewCtrlFileExists As String
Public wb As Workbook
Public ctrl As Worksheet
Public xData As Worksheet
Public iHeaders As Integer
Public numNames As Integer
Public FirstRow As Integer
Public LastRow As Integer
Public LastCol As Integer

'Powerpoint
Public myPres As PowerPoint.Presentation

'Error handling
Public errArea As String
Public g_objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Public g_scrText As Scripting.TextStream
Public Msg, Style, Response

Sub CreateDashboards()

'1. Add PPT refs to Excel: Tools > References > Microsoft PowerPoint
'2. Add error logging: Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    
iHeaders = 0
numNames = 0
FirstRow = 0
LastRow = 0
LastCol = 0

    On Error GoTo Failure
    
Startup:
    errArea = "Startup"
    
    Set wb = Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Sheet1.Activate 'Control sheet
    Set ctrl = wb.ActiveSheet
    
    'File names
    ProjectName = ctrl.Range("ProjectName") 'project name
    Dim PptTemplateName As String
    PptTemplateName = ctrl.Range("PptTemplateName") 'template name
    
    'Get data
    Sheet2.Activate 'Data
    Set xData = wb.ActiveSheet
    
    iHeaders = 2
    FirstRow = iHeaders + 1
    LastRow = xData.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    LastCol = xData.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    numNames = LastRow - iHeaders

Initialize:
    errArea = "Initialize"
    
    ctrl.Range("PptReportName") = ProjectName 'PptReportName: default is project name, but also user-defined if desired

    'Round and clean data
    Call CleanData
    
    'get E chart data
    Dim rngEcols As Range
    Set rngEcols = xData.Range("1:1")
    Dim iEcount As Integer, lEstartCol As Integer, lEendCol As Integer
    iEcount = Excel.Application.CountIf(rngEcols, "E")
    lEstartCol = WorksheetFunction.Match("E", rngEcols, 0)
    lEendCol = lEstartCol + iEcount - 1

    'get max value for all E chart data
    Dim dEmaxvalue As Single 'decimal
    Dim dEAxisMax As Single 'decimal
    dEmaxvalue = Application.Max(xData.Range(Cells(iHeaders + 1, lEstartCol), Cells(LastRow, lEendCol)))
    'define the axis max as dEmaxvalue rounded up to nearest 10%, then add 5%
    dEAxisMax = Application.RoundUp(dEmaxvalue, 1) + 0.05
    
    'get attribute label positions
    Dim lEstart, lEend
    Set lEstart = xData.Cells((FirstRow - 1), lEstartCol)
    Set lEend = xData.Cells((FirstRow - 1), lEendCol)

    'get PPT
    Set myPres = GetOpenOrClosedPPT(wb.Path & "\" & PptTemplateName & ".pptx")
    myPres.Windows(1).Activate

    'transpose attribute labels into PPT E chart
    With myPres.Slides(1).Shapes("E").Chart
        .ChartData.Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:" & Cells(iEcount + 1, 1).Address & "") _
            = Excel.Application.Transpose(xData.Range("" & lEstart.Address & ":" & lEend.Address & ""))
        
        Dim rngEdata As Range 'get E data range
        Set rngEdata = Range("A1:" & Cells(iEcount + 1, 2).Address & "")
        Dim sEchartsource As String
        sEchartsource = "='Sheet1'!" & rngEdata.Address & "" 'set chart data source to E data range
        .SetSourceData Source:=sEchartsource
        .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = dEAxisMax
    End With

Execute:
    errArea = "Execute"
    
    'create slide for each row of data
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To numNames - 1 'template slide already exists
        myPres.Slides(1).Duplicate
    Next i
    
    'populate slides with data
    Dim lDataRow As Integer, lSldNum As Integer
    lSldNum = 1
    lDataRow = lSldNum + iHeaders 'account for headers
    Dim Slide As Slide
    Dim y As Integer
    
'$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
'$$$$$$$ Begin populate chart data $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
'$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

    For Each Slide In myPres.Slides
        errArea = "Slide " & lSldNum
        myPres.Slides(lSldNum).Select
        With myPres.Slides(lSldNum)
            
            With .Shapes("B").Chart
                .ChartData.Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("B2").Value = xData.Cells(lDataRow, 5) * 100
                .Refresh
                .ChartData.Workbook.Close
            End With
            
            With .Shapes("C").Chart
                .ChartData.Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("B2").Value = xData.Cells(lDataRow, 6) * 100
                .Refresh
                .ChartData.Workbook.Close
            End With
            
            With .Shapes("E").Chart
                For y = 1 To iEcount
                    .ChartData.Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1 + y, 2) = xData.Cells(lDataRow, (lEstartCol - 1) + y)
                Next y
                .Refresh
                .ChartData.Workbook.Close
            End With
            
            With .Shapes("G").Chart
                .ChartData.Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("B2").Value = xData.Cells(lDataRow, 11) * 100
                .Refresh
                .ChartData.Workbook.Close
            End With
            
            With .Shapes("K").Chart
                .ChartData.Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("B2").Value = xData.Cells(lDataRow, 13) * 100
                .Refresh
                .ChartData.Workbook.Close
            End With
            
        End With
        
        'increment slide & row indices
        lSldNum = lSldNum + 1
        lDataRow = lDataRow + 1
        
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        DoEvents
    Next Slide
    myPres.Slides(1).Select 'return to starting position
    
    GoTo Success

Success:
    
    'Write to log file
    Call LogFile_Write(wb.Path, "LoadDashboards", "SUCCESS", numNames & " names' data loaded")
    
    myPres.SaveAs Filename:=wb.Path & "\" & ProjectName & ".pptx"
    
    'Notify user
    AppActivate Application.Caption
    MsgBox "Data loaded successfully.", vbSystemModal + vbInformation
    
    Exit Sub


Failure:
    
    'write to log file
    Call LogFile_Write(wb.Path, "LoadDashboards", "ERROR", errArea & " - " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description)
    
    'Notify user
    AppActivate Application.Caption
    MsgBox "An error occurred. Please try again.", vbSystemModal + vbCritical, "Error"

    Exit Sub

    
End Sub


Public Function CleanData()

    On Error GoTo Failure
    
    Dim x As Integer 'Rows
    Dim y As Integer 'Cols
    For y = 3 To LastCol
        Select Case y
            'Round raw data to 2 decimal places
            Case 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 13 'E attributes data first, then E average
                For x = FirstRow To LastRow
                        xData.Cells(x, y) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(xData.Cells(x, y), 2)
                Next x
        End Select
    Next y
    
    Exit Function

Failure:
    
    'Write to log file
    Call LogFile_Write(wb.Path, "CleanData", "ERROR", " - " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description)
    
    'Notify user
    AppActivate Application.Caption
    MsgBox "An error occurred. Please try again.", vbSystemModal + vbCritical, "Error"

End Function

Public Function GetOpenOrClosedPPT(ByVal sTargetFullName As String) As Object

Dim funcPPTApp As Object
Dim p As PowerPoint.Presentation

On Error Resume Next
Set funcPPTApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application") 'Check if PPT is running
PPTisOpen:
    If Not (funcPPTApp Is Nothing) Then 'If PPT is running
        For Each p In funcPPTApp.Presentations 'For all open Presentations
            If p.FullName = sTargetFullName Then 'If name matches target Presentation
                Set GetOpenOrClosedPPT = p 'Set function result to Presentation
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next p
        GoTo PPTisNotOpen 'If PPT is running but file is not open
    End If
PPTisNotOpen:
    Set funcPPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    funcPPTApp.Presentations.Open (sTargetFullName) 'Open target Presentation
    Set GetOpenOrClosedPPT = funcPPTApp.Presentations(sTargetFullName) 'Set function result to Presentation

End Function

Public Function LogFile_Write( _
         ByVal sPath As String _
        , ByVal sProcedure As String _
        , ByVal sType As String _
        , ByVal sDescription As String)

    Dim sFilePath As String
    sFilePath = sPath & "\debug_log.txt" 'logfile path
    
    Dim sText As String
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    If (g_objFSO Is Nothing) Then
       Set g_objFSO = New FileSystemObject 'Initialize var
    End If
    If (g_scrText Is Nothing) Then
       If (g_objFSO.FileExists(sFilePath) = False) Then 'If logfile does not already exist, create one
          Set g_scrText = g_objFSO.OpenTextFile(sFilePath, IOMode.ForWriting, True)
          sText = "File created:" & Format(Date, "DD MMM YYYY") & vbCrLf
       Else
          Set g_scrText = g_objFSO.OpenTextFile(sFilePath, IOMode.ForAppending)
       End If
    End If
    'Append new line to existing text
    sText = sText & "- " & _
            sProcedure & " " & _
            sType & ": " & _
            Format(Date, "DD MMM YYYY") & "-" & _
            Time() & " || " & _
            sDescription
    g_scrText.WriteLine sText
    g_scrText.Close
    Set g_scrText = Nothing
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    Set g_scrText = Nothing
    Call MsgBox("Unable to write to log file", vbCritical, "LogFile_Write")

End Function
```

Comment: If you think the Application.Wait is causing issues, I would recommend swapping it out with the Delay function here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49389093/delay-macro-to-allow-events-to-finish

Comment: @Tragamor my previous wording may have been confusing. I do not think Application.Wait is causing any issues - that was meant to be a band-aid solution to my problems, but it does not fix everything.

Comment: Haven't worked with charts in PPT much, but you might consider creating the charts in your Excel file then copypicture >> paste, size, position in PPT.  Seems like there's possibly significant overhead to having the underlying chart worksheets in PPT which you could avoid by using pasted graphics instead (unless you really need "live" charts?)

Comment: @TimWilliams I've gone down that path before, and unfortunately "live" charts are the only acceptable solution for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Try sleep command of windows. (sleep will pause the code for sometime)
To let charts sometime to refresh.

Type below line on top of the program:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As LongPtr)
```

In the code, after updating the charts and before closing the chart workbook,
Type:

```
sleep 5000
```

5000 is for 5 seconds, you can modify for your choice.

Regards,
Balu.