# Wait 10 seconds on VBA

Tags: excel, vba, wait

I'm trying to open an Excel file, make some testing changes, wait for 10 seconds, make one more change, save the file and close Excel by VBA.
I have already accomplished every step, but the 10 sec waiting. It gives me the warning of an 'Application' object mandatory.
Could you'll help me on how to use this 'wait application' correctly, please?
Find below my coding (sorry, I'm a beginner user).

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
objExcel.Visible = True 
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\\xxxxxx\xxxxxxx\vbsTest.xlsx")
objExcel.Cells(3,5).Value = "new value"
objExcel.Cells(3,6).Value = "other value"
objExcel.Cells(3,4).Value = "delete"

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))

objExcel.Cells(3,5).Value = "something different"
objExcel.Cells(3,4).Value = ""
objWorkbook.Save
objWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
```

Comment: Change `Application` to `objExcel`.

Comment: It works. Thank you.

Comment: `Application.Wait` suspends all Excel activity and may interfere with other operation. You may prefer a delay function: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49389093/3688861