# "Call" macro does not execute but will manually

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone know why my macro to "call" other macros is not running the last macro called **SetupDetails**? It runs successfully when pushed manually/individually.

```
Sub MainMacro()

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Call InjectAllSqlsAndRefreshConnections
   Call SetupDashboard
   Call SetupDetails
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Is there something wrong with the body of this SetupDetails macro itself? I've fiddled with it a lot and nothing seems to be solve this issue.

```
Sub SetupDetails()

Set Details = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Details")
Set Raw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SQL - Bugs w Goals")

Dim x As Integer
Dim CorrectOrder As Variant
Dim i As Variant
Dim tblComp As ListObject
Dim LastRow As Integer

Details.Activate
Details.UsedRange.Clear
If Raw.AutoFilterMode Then Raw.ShowAllData
Raw.UsedRange.Copy
Details.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

With Details.UsedRange
        'Dedupe
        .AutoFilter Field:=23, Criteria1:="0"
        .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilter

        'Delete unneeded columns
        .Range("D:E,G:G, I:K, M:N, O:P,R:U, W:Z, AD:AD, AF:AG,AK:AK").Delete

        'Rename Columns
        .Range("A1").Value = "ID"
        .Range("B1").Value = "Summary"
        .Range("C1").Value = "Status"
        .Range("E1").Value = "Class"
        .Range("H1").Value = "Goals"
        .Range("I1").Value = "Progress Status"
        .Range("J1").Value = "Open/Closed Status"
        .Range("K1").Value = "Blocked Status"
        .Range("M1").Value = "Remaining Time"
        .Range("N1").Value = "Total Time"
        .Range("O1").Value = "Dept"

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Details.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Details.UsedRange, xlYes).Name = "DetailsView"
        Details.ListObjects("DetailsView").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"

        'Reorder
        Set tblComp = Details.ListObjects("DetailsView")
        CorrectOrder = Array("Goals", "Dept", "Team", "ID", "Status", "Class", "Summary", "Due Date", "Deadline Stage (Milestone)", "Actual Time", "Remaining Time", "Total Time", "Progress Status", "Open/Closed Status", "Blocked Status")
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each i In CorrectOrder
            Columns(tblComp.ListColumns(i).Range.Column).Cut
            Columns(tblComp.ListColumns.Count + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Next i
        On Error GoTo 0


End With

'Formatting
With Details
            .Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 60
            .Columns(1).WrapText = True
            .Columns(7).ColumnWidth = 60
            .Columns(7).WrapText = True
            For x = 1 To .Columns.Count
                Columns(x).EntireColumn.AutoFit
            Next x
            Cells.Select
            Selection.Columns.AutoFit
End With

'Links
LastRow = Details.Cells(Details.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
With Details.UsedRange
                        For x = 2 To LastRow
                            Cells(x, "D").Activate
                            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveCell, Address:="URL HERE" & ActiveCell.Text, TextToDisplay:=ActiveCell.Text
                            Next x
    End With
    
    Sheets("Report").Activate
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: I guess this is impossible to say from outside. Have you debugged the code using F8 or breakpoints? Is the sub not executed all all (sounds unlikely)? Does the previous routine return successfully or maybe stop the code already?

Comment: There are many factors that could occur, e.g., having the items in different modules or having something by `private`.  My suggestion would be to use `Application.Run "Module#.MacroName"` as opposed to `Call`.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.run

Comment: There's no need to use `Application.Run` here, assuming the macro is in the same workbook.  Even `Call` is deprecated these days: you can just use `SetupDetails` without the `Call`

Comment: Can you describe "not running" and "this issue?"

Comment: My first thoughts would be that maybe 'Details' has not be updated by the time the third macro is called if either of the first two macros are using asynchronous calls. It may be as simple as adding in a delay between then functions or checking to make sure they have completed.

Comment: The first 2 run fine: InjectAllSqlsAndRefreshConnections and SetupDashboard. I know SetupDetails is not completing correctly because the data does not change; however, the macro doesn't throw any errors and finishes normally. If I run SetupDetails by itself (not through the Main macro) it completes and the data is transformed as expected. It's just when run via the Main macro. @Tragamor - could you let me know how to add a delay or to check if they're completed?

Comment: Delay function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49389094/3688861 or to do a check if they are complete, you can set your functions to return as TRUE once the macro has finished. In the main loop you can use a do-loop to check an assigned flag variable until it is true or times out.

Comment: Why not put a breakpoint at the beginning of `SetupDetails` and then step through it after it gets called from `MainMacro`

Comment: FYI this `Columns(tblComp.ListColumns(i).Range.Column).Cut` is not scoped to your `With` block, so will operate on the ActiveSheet, which may not be the same sheet as `Details`

Comment: ..and there are a few other instances of ranges not scoped to the containing `With` block - maybe start by reviewing those and fixing as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out! Turns out the macro **InjectAllSqlsAndRefreshConnections**, which does exactly what it sounds like was not completing the data refresh until it continued on. So any macros afterwards which depend on the refreshed data were appearing unchanged as it was still using the unrefreshed data.

Solved this by turning off Enable Background Refresh in the data query Connection Properties. This way it forces the query to complete before continuing processing.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCvEm.jpg)